# wordpress my own plugin: ajax always returns 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I wrote a plugin, which uses ajax. The plugin should allow users (if logged in or not) to delete a value on database.

My Problem is, that the ajax response ALWAYS is NULL and I have no idea why! I googled for hours and I tried everthing... Here are my scripts:

```
function my_script_enqueuer(){

    global $post; 
    $content = $post->post_content;
    if(has_shortcode($content, 'shortcode')){
        wp_register_script('my_script', 
            WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-plugin/js/my-plugin.js',
            array('jquery'));

        wp_localize_script('my_script',
            'myAjax', 
            array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script');
    } 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

add_action('wp_ajax_del_value', 'del_value');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_del_value', 'del_value');

function del_value(){

    $val = $_POST['val'];
    echo $val;

    //$wpdb->...an so on
    die();
}
```

**and here my ajax (my_plugin.js)**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
jQuery(document).on('click', '.delval',  function($){   

    var val = this.id;

        jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                    data: {action:"del_value", val: val},
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.type = "success"){
                            console.log(response);
                        }else{
                            console.log("Error");
                        }
                    }

                });
});

});
```

Comment: If you console.log val just after setting a value to it, what does it print?

Comment: It shows the right value. e.g. 1 or 2 or 3...

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the code here. I duplicated the example provided and it worked for me.

When I've run into problems like this in the past it's usually boiled down to one of two problems:

1. The browser thinks this is a cross-domain request.  Solution: make sure that the domain in myAjax.ajaxurl matches the domain you see in your browser location bar.
2. jQuery isn't interpreting the mime type of the response correctly.  You're not specifying the return type.  Solution: try including a dataType: "text" key/pair with your jQuery.ajax call; or try encoding the response as JSON.

Comment: Thank you tbcrowe. I just figured it out, that the script works if the user is logged in. It does not work, if the user is NOT logged in. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I had the same variable twice (different use) in my whole script. Unfortunately, the

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_del_value', 'del_value');
```

...was...

```
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_del_value', 'del_value');
```

...in my script.

Sorry for that. I hope that my script will help others sometimes, somehow.

Greets,
Yab86